# Create dataset with exist dynamic table name and datetime parameter SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures, reporting-services

Table involved

[image: 1]

I would like to create dataset with datetime parameter, when user choose date, it automatically select data from the date table as in the picture (dynamic table name).

SP created is as shown

[image: 2]

Already use method stored procedure, but then I had trouble when joining the stored procedure with another table. Can you suggest the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: im very new to this site, thank you for the guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing each day in a separate table is probably not the best way to go but more on that later, to solve the immediate problem....

You can dump the results of your SP into a temp table and join to that.

I have assumed here that your `SensorDataRainfall` table ( the one without a date) is the same structure at the ones with dates.

Your dataset query would look like this.

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #SDR FROM dbo.SensorDataRainfall -- create an empty table to put the results in.

INSERT INTO #SDR EXEC spGetDataRainfall @year, @month -- dump data from the SP

SELECT * 
    FROM #SDR a 
    JOIN myOtherTable b on a.column = b.column
```

---

**However** There are a few issues with your general approach.

Having data which is essentially the same data split by dates is not very scalable, even if the amount of data is very small, it's just not a good approach. You should probably investigate the process that creates there tables in the first place and insert the data into a table which has the same structure but also include columns for the year and month. This way all the data will be in a single table and can easily queried for a single month of across multiple months, years.

Comment: thank you! your answer very helpful sir. regarding the data split by month is because data involved are too large. average data per month re around 500k rows and ongoing.  But if u have ways on how to handle this vast data in a single table (main purpose to produce ssrs report), i will gladly follow your guidance

Answer (score 0):

You can use table functions. you able join T.F with another table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_test] 
(
--INPUT PARAMETERS
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(ID NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO @output (ID)  
        EXEC('SELECT 1 AS A')
    RETURN 
END
```